# Why are there Hawaiians in First Cow?

Tags: plot-explanation, historical-accuracy, first-cow

*First Cow* is set in the Oregon frontier in 1820.  In one part of the movie, one of the main characters, Cookie, passes out from a head injury and is rescued by a man and woman speaking a non-English language.  I assume for the following reasons that this language is Hawaiian:

- According to [the screenplay](https://deadline.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/FIRST-COW-screenplay.pdf), the man and woman in this scene "look Hawaiian" (p. 61).
- The movie's end credits list roles for "Hawaiian Man" and "Hawaiian Woman".
- According to [the movie's IMDb entry](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9231040/), one of the film's languages is Hawaiian.

Is it historically accurate, or at least plausible, that Hawaiians would be found in the Oregon wilderness in 1820?  (For example, did significant numbers of Hawaiians actually come to the Pacific Northwest as settlers, slaves, or migrant workers?)  If not, why did the writers anachronistically insert them into the film?  Is there some sort of narrative or symbolic significance to having Cookie rescued by Hawaiians in particular, as opposed to the Native Americans indigenous to the region?

Comment: If it helps: "*moved from Hawaii to Oregon in 2019: 2,798 (ranked #8 in US mainland)*". And [this article](https://www.thecollector.com/19th-century-hawaii-history-american-interventionism/) says that, as early as 1810's, Hawaiian had began to move to mainland.

Comment: I have also found some articles of dubious quality that suggest Hawaiians sometimes moved to the US during the 19th century.

Comment: @OldPadawan: No, I don't think migration figures from 200 years after the movie is set are in any way relevant. I also don't see where the linked article mentions migration in the 1810s. Could you quote the passage you're referring to?

Comment: 1/2. From wikipedia : "*the population of Native Hawaiians in Hawaii declined from an unknown number prior to 1778 (commonly estimated to be around 300,000), to around 142,000 in the 1820s based on the first census conducted by American missionaries, 82,203 in the 1850 Hawaiian Kingdom census*".

Comment: 2/2. "*American immigration, led by Protestant missionaries, and Native Hawaiian outmigration, mostly on whaling ships, began almost immediately after Cook's arrival.*"(1776). You have massive arrival of foreigners on ships for commercial purposes, I'm pretty sure a ***lot*** of Hawaiians step onboard to leave their island. Crossing the numbers above makes sense to me.

Comment: I think that's an unwarranted assumption, especially considering that your same source implies that [the decline in population was due largely to diseases introduced by Cook and later colonizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonial_epidemic_disease_in_Hawai'i).

Comment: I’m confused. Are you saying that you don’t believe any Hawaiians immigrated to the US in the 19th century? Because it is well documented that some did.

Comment: @Psychonaut : I'm pretty sure at least two Hawaiians survived the deseases and were able to make it to Oregon to shoot a scene :) joke aside: as soon as people were able to travel by boat "around" the world (say +/- 1500+ AD), and move from one country to another, they spread all over the world. I just tried to back up my thoughts with some data, but didn't make *that* much research...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, I've found some sources saying that, as early as 1800's, Hawaiians (along other Pacific Islanders such as Japanese, Filipinos, New-Zealanders...) were already on US mainland, hired to work on ships (often whalers), or for fur trade (Hudson's Bay Company).

> Native Hawaiians arrived in the Pacific Northwest as early as 1787. Some went out of curiosity; many others were recruited as seamen or as workers in the fur trade ([University of Hawai'i Press](https://uhpress.hawaii.edu/title/leaving-paradise-indigenous-hawaiians-in-the-pacific-northwest-1787-1898/))

1. [Aloha, Oregon! Hawaiians In Northwest History](https://odnp.uoregon.edu/2011/06/01/aloha-oregon-hawaiians-in-northwest-history/)
2. [Hawaiians in Oregon: A brief history](https://bendbranches.com/2016/02/07/hawaiians-oregon-history-now/)
3. [Hawaiians Leaving Home](https://imagesofoldhawaii.com/hawaiians-leaving-home/#:%7E:text=There%20is%20historical%20evidence%20suggesting,them%20in%20the%20Pacific%20Northwest.)
4. [Hawai'i and the American Penetration of the Northeastern Pacific, 1800-1845](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3633049)
5. [Hudson's Bay Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson%27s_Bay_Company)<sup>1</sup>

So, about your question:

> Is it historically accurate, or at least plausible, that Hawaiians would be found in the Oregon wilderness in 1820?

To me, the answer is a clear **yes**.

---

<sup>1. [Frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontier_(2016_TV_series)), staring Hawaiian [Jason Momoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Momoa) shows some historical points (even though JM plays a half-Irish, half-Cree outlaw and not a Pacific Islander)</sup>